# SWF cannot connects to DB (using AMFPHP ) while run through browser, but in debug mode it works fine

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, amfphp

its few days i'm stock with a issue using amfphp 2 in my actionscript project.

i have an actionscript project which gets the data from db through amfphp, when i run the complied swf in debug mode or just run through flash player it works fine , but once i wrap it with html and open it through browser it never gets the data from db, dose any body can help me what is going on ?

i have added these lines at the first of the project , but still through browser ( i've tried , Chrome, Firefox and safari) it cannot connects to db.

```
        Security.allowDomain("*");          
        Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, download the debugger Flash Player extension for your browser. When running Flash content in debugger it will tell you what errors occur.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp11

Also, I'd suggest to check out the Crossdomain policy file on the server you're trying to communicate with. To be able to communicate with any servers from Flash Player you need to allow it on the server by using a crossdomain.xml file.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Good luck,
Rob

Comment: Thanks Rob for the suggestions, i did the steps you mentioned , but i dono why its still not working . the crossdomain file also which i put in the server is like this : 
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
     <cross-domain-policy>
     <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
     </cross-domain-policy> 

 the application works fine when i run the swf file with flash player (out of browser) , but only once i open it through browser it cannot get the data from db

Comment: Have you installed the debugger player for your browser? If so, does it throw any errors when you run the app?

Comment: Thanks Rob, i Could solve the problem by changing the crossdomain file content to this :

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

im still not sure why it happend to not working with previous syntax but anyway thanks for your help :)